# Regarding my salesforce service cloud certification results

Tags: certification

I took my salesforce serivce cloud consultant exam on july 18, 2018.I took onsite exam. After submitted the exam i didn't see any exam results and even i didn't got any results to my email. I opened case also but i didn't got any response from them. Is there any best way to contact them.

Comment: Have you tried tweeting to Salesforce U or Trailhead ?

Comment: Really i don't know about that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not belong on this site and is rather a question that should be directed to [Salesforce Certification](http://certification.salesforce.com/open-a-case)

Answer (score 3):

If you could open this: [http://certification.salesforce.com](http://certification.salesforce.com/), you would find a link under **Support** tab that says: **Guided Help**. Clicking on it would opens a chat box(right corner) where you can provide all your information and submit a ticket. With this, a follow up email will be sent out from Salesforce and a Salesforce support representative would happy to help you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did this process after completing my exam but till now there is no response from them.

Comment: @AbhiRam if you've done this already, and got no answer, why did you mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @AbhiRam If you already have a case open with the Salesforce, don't worry, they would help you out. I had a similar issue(not same as yours) as well and it took almost a week to get it sorted out. All I would do is: responding back to the email you have received with the case number. This will make your response as a comment on the actual case and might escalate it.

Answer (score -2):

**Partner Portal & Chatter**

Contact someone via your Salesforce Partner Portal or Partner Chatter Groups.

- [Salesforce Partner Portal](https://partners.salesforce.com/)
- [Official: Partner Community](https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001s6I)
- [Partner Service Cloud Certification Training Chatter Group](https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009Odo)

**Email**

Email address: certification@salesforce.com

**Twitter**

Twitter: [Trailhead / Salesforce University](https://twitter.com/salesforceu?lang=en)

**Telephone**

Call them on: 0800 0921223 (UK Freephone)